# Problems implementing synchronized plotline and tooltips for highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

I'm trying to implement synchronized highcharts as in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j7hk1802/ but I'm having problems.

The synchronized plotline only shows at the very left or right of the plots (where there is no data), as soon as I move the plot line to where there is data the synchronization breaks and I start getting a lot of console errors:

```
highcharts.src.js:21444 Uncaught TypeError: (c || []).forEach is not a function
    at n.applyInactiveState (highcharts.src.js:21444)
    at e.refresh (highcharts.src.js:20820)
    at test2.html:119
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.d.<computed> [as each] (highcharts.src.js:2207)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (test2.html:112)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-latest.js:4641)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-latest.js:4309)
```

This relates to the following code:

```
container.mousemove(function(evt) {

    x = evt.clientX - chart.plotLeft - offset.left;
    y = evt.clientY - chart.plotTop - offset.top;
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
    var xVal = xAxis.toValue(x, true);
    //remove old plot line and draw new plot line (crosshair) for this chart
    var xAxis1 = chart1.xAxis[0];
    var points1 = chart1.series[0].points;

    Highcharts.each(points1, function(point, i) {
      if (i + 1 < points1.length && point.x <= xVal && points1[i + 1].x > xVal) {
        //reset state
        point.setState();
        points1[i + 1].setState();

        if (xVal - point.x <= points1[i + 1].x - xVal) {
          chart1.tooltip.refresh(point);
          point.setState('hover');
        } else {
          chart1.tooltip.refresh(points1[i + 1]);
          points1[i + 1].setState('hover');
        }
      }
    });
```

I've tried to create a jsfiddle to replicate the error, but I'm still struggling to get functioning charts to show in jsfiddle, however my attempt can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/a72csgro/6/

I'd really appreciate some help as this is the last step I need to be able to create dynamic charts for my weather data.

Sebastian Wędzel's solution below works to remove the console errors, however the first chart is synchronizing to a different entry to the other charts:
[image: Image showing mis-alignment of first chart to subsequent chart and additional entires in third and fourth charts]

Also the tooltips for the 3rd and 4th charts I've added aren't showing the correct series, I'm sure I've not updated the code correctly for these charts, but can't see my error.

My new code is here https://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/sj90gw4x/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated code to display the correct tooltips for all four charts is here [jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/61bs9nfq](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/61bs9nfq) and was provided by Sebastian Wędzel.

In order to fix the alignment issue caused by different sized axis labels you must specify the same sized left and right margins for all charts as follows

```
chart: {
      marginLeft: 100, //size of left margin in pixels
      marginRight: 100, //size of right margin in pixels
      }
```

Comment: Here is a link to the fully working version on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/716jx4n9/](http://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/716jx4n9/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem which you are struggling to is that you pasted only one point as an argument into the **tooltip.refresh** function, meanwhile shared tooltip requires an array of points which should be displayed. I do some changes to fit your custom code with the shared tooltip.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yrkjvft2/

```
function syncronizeCrossHairs(chart) {
  var container = $(chart.container),
    offset = container.offset(),
    x;

  container.mousemove(function(evt) {
    x = evt.clientX - chart.plotLeft - offset.left;
    //remove old plot line and draw new plot line (crosshair) for this chart
    var xAxis1 = chart1.xAxis[0],
      points = [],
      points1 = [],
      e = chart1.pointer.normalize(evt); // Find coordinates within the chart   

    chart1.series.forEach(s => {
      var point = s.searchPoint(e, true)
      if (point) {
        point.setState();
        points.push(point)
      }
    })

    if (points) {
      var number = 0;
      Highcharts.each(points, function(p, i) {
        if (!p.series.visible) {
          points.splice(i - number, 1);
          number++;
        }
      })
      if (points.length) {
        chart1.tooltip.refresh(points); // Show the tooltip
      }
    }

    xAxis1.removePlotLine("myPlotLineId");
    xAxis1.addPlotLine({
      value: chart.xAxis[0].translate(x, true),
      width: 1,
      color: 'red',
      //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
      id: "myPlotLineId"
    });
...
```

Comment: Thanks this works to syncronise the plotline and tool tip across the different  charts, however the second and subsequent charts are not aligning to the same entry as the first. I'll post a picture showing this.

Comment: I've added a new jsfiddle with the code for the four charts, I'd really apprecieate it if you can tell me what's going wrong with the alignment of the first chart and why my added 3rd and 4th charts have incorrect tooltips

Comment: Here is a fixed code for working tooltip for 4 charts. The difference which you have shown on the pictures are output that `chart.plotWidth` is different for chart 3 and 4 (check console) - the difference occurs because the labels for yAxis are longer in chart3 and 4.

Comment: I've made a working jsfiddle with the tooltip issue here [https://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/7fuoe5ks/11/](https://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/7fuoe5ks/11/)

Comment: My mistake, something went wrong while attaching the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/61bs9nfq/

Comment: Thank you very much, that has sorted out the issue with the additional entries in the tooltip. In an earlier comment, you mention the offset issue is caused by the chart.plotWidth being different for each graph. I've tried specifying a value for that variable but it doesn't seem to change anything. Can you adapt your example to show how to standardise the plotWidth property for charts with different axis labels?

Comment: OK, so figure this out. I need to set the chart.marginLeft and chart.marginRight properties to be the same size for all four charts. Once that is done everything aligns perfectly. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I see that you found a satisfying solution. Perfect!